# Software for drawing diagrams 

Tags: mathematical-software

Dear All,

Can someone recommend a simple graphics-based software to create figures for a latex document?

Thanks!

Comment: (1) Why not ask this on the tex stackexchange website? (2) I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "graphics-based". Is it software that uses the mouse for input?

Comment: This is definitely off-topic for mathoverflow but if you explained a little more as to what you wanted it would be on-topic at http://tex.stackexchange.com For example, if you are interested in having a GUI you could look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26972/86 If there is a particular type of diagram that you are interested in, we might already have an answer on TeX-SX and if not, then ask and someone is bound to have a sensible answer.

Comment: 1. This should be community wiki. 2. with the proviso of 1, the question is certainly of interest. 3. However, the answer depends on the meaning of "figure", so the question should be edited.

Comment: Meta discussion: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1177/software-recommendation-for-latex-diagrams/

Answer (score 2):

I like to use TikZ for LaTex because it looks really clean, you have the same fonts then in the text, you can even use it easily inside formulae etc. But you have 
to "program" the pictures using coordinates, so it has a bit of a learning curve.

Some examples of TikZ can be found here
http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/area/mathematics/

Answer (score 1):

I use xfig on linux.

Comment: is there a good PC alternative?

Comment: Some people like inkscape.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use it myself (what I use isn't inexpensive), but my students seem to like [Ipe](http://tclab.kaist.ac.kr/ipe/).

Comment: What DO you use?

Comment: Adobe Illustrator, mostly.

Answer (score 1):

I use Graphics in Mathematica, or xypic package for LaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

jPicEdt has served me well in the past.

http://jpicedt.sourceforge.net/