# Java library for SDP

Tags: global-optimization, convexity

People who frequently code semi definite programs, is there any java library for solving sdps? I have tried my luck but all I can find is C/C++ libraries or matlab toolboxes. I can write wrappers to call C from Java but will be much useful if there is indeed a java library.

Comment: This would probably fare better on StackOverflow as it is a programming question.

Comment: I tried stackoverflow prior to this. There is a very small number of people who use things other than cplex, so it wasn't fruitful.

Comment: I meant to say "small number of ppl at stackoverflow".

Comment: Definitely not appropriate, voting to close.

Comment: I really cannot see what the problem with this question is. In particular, as SO does not seem to be a good place to ask it.

Comment: @quid: if the OP asked whether the iPhone implementation of Angry Birds were better than the Android version, that would probably get bounced from SO, but it would not make it suitable for MO. "Software for solving SDP in Java" is just not a math research question

Comment: @Igor: Your angry birds example does not have any intersection with MO. My post is not a math research question but chances that someone in MO community might have encountered this are higher than in SO. Anyways, feel feel to vote it down - let the votes decide.

Comment: @I J: (a) I have already voted to close, so that's done. (b) the probability someone on MO has encountered the mean value theorem is quite close to one, but it does not make asking questions about the proof appropriate. (c) but also: no one sane would implement SDP in Java, since you would lose at least an order of magnitude over a C implementation. Java has an annoying but serviceable foreign function interface. If you want to know how to use it, I am sure you would get  $10^6$ hits on SO.

Comment: @Igor: you recently considered it a suitable MO question to ask about software to create figures/diagrams ( http://mathoverflow.net/questions/78520/ ). The present question seems considerably closer to maths.  

Comment: @Igor in reply to (c): Harsh words! Well it depends where you are coming from. Sometimes you have to use someone's code that is only in java and sometimes you are willing to take a hit in perf for design reasons. Lets not get into that. About the java interface with C: I guess you are talking about JNI, I am aware of that.

Comment: @quid: (a) I thought for some time before asking that question and I decided to go ahead because (b) mathematicians use those tools all the time, and no one else does (for mathematical figures anyhow). Publishing papers and giving talks is an integral part of research, so a community of research mathematicians is the best place to ask about best practices. SDP in java, not so much, bluntly speaking, because the question is not interesting, and the answer, if it existed, could be found with google in seconds. If the OP had a class of SDPs he needed to understand and find the best tool for,sure.

Comment: @Igor: not sure we are talking about the same question. It was asked by somebody going by 'Lost' you defeneded it in a comment. 
Reagrding the latter parts: I assume to get the most useful one (if any exist) is somehow implict. How easy or not this is to find, well I really don't know. But perhaps the question will turn up something useful. And if not, it will anyway fall unanswered into the depths of MO anyway. So I don't see much need to close it.
 

Comment: @quid: I am not sure we really disagree all that much on the issues, it is the last part of your last comment which is probably at the root of the disagreement; there have been a lot of silly questions on MO lately (and I admit that @I J's question is much less silly than the worst), and while most of them would eventually disappear, having MO swamped by this stuff is damaging. I really have no idea what to do, and I certainly agree that overreaction is a danger...

Answer (score 2):

I think the following might fit the bill:

[Mosek Java API](http://mosek.com/products/product-overview/mosek/java-api/)

If you don't want to pay \$\$, then you might want to implement an interface to one of the following: [List of SDP solvers](http://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~helmberg/sdp_software.html)

However, I am not aware of a pure Java implementation. If you can incorporate a compiled FORTRAN or C library in Java, then you need not restrict yourself to native Java implementations.

Comment: Unfortunately Mosek does not solve semi definite programming problems (http://docs.mosek.com/kb/Can_MOSEK_solve_semi-definite_optimizati.html). I've decided to write a java interface to CSDP since it looks certain that there are no existing java interfaces. 

Comment: I remember talking to one of the developers from Mosek several months ago, and I recollect him mentioning SDP abilities --- but maybe it is not yet commercial.
