# How do you generate math figures for academic papers?

Tags: journals, mathematics-education, recreational-mathematics, mathematical-software, online-resources

Good day! I am looking for any tool that would allow me to generate a figure similar to the figures embedded in the paper by King et al. (2020) titled *"Trigonometry: a brief conversation."*

King, C., Evelyn, T., Ye, F., & Carvajal, B. (2020). Trigonometry: A Brief Conversation. Open Educational Resources. https://academicworks.cuny.edu/qb_oers/167/

Comment: Maybe better suited to [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)? Anyway, [TikZ](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/TikZ_package) is a fairly standard LaTeX package for making figures like those.

Comment: for the diagrams you have many options; I use LaTeXit to have labels in the same font as the text.

Comment: Possibly MetaPost (https://tug.org/metapost.html)

Comment: @LSpice --- yep, asked a decade ago, with similar answers, and closed for similar reasons as mentioned by Nathaniel. [Software for drawing diagrams](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78520/software-for-drawing-diagrams)

Comment: Inkscape is easy to use.  TikZ can be difficult at first, but one can obtain good results with it.

Comment: [math.se]: [Software for drawing geometry diagrams](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1985) and other [questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1985). [math.meta.se]: [Creating diagrams](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9632) and other [questions linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/9632).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To complement Kostya's answer, here is a way to turn hand-drawings into something looking vaguely professional using **inkscape**, very quickly (and for free).

1. **Draw** something on paper.
2. Take a **photo** in good light conditions, and drag the photo file into inkscape.
3. Select the photo in inkscape and press **Shift + Alt + B** at the same time (this starts the *bitmap* function).
4. Tweak the parameters until you're happy with them (click "update" to preview), then click "OK".
5. Delete the underlying image, an svg (vector graphics) picture will have been generated on top of it.
6. Go to "document properties" to tweak the page size.
7. Press Ctrl + Shift + E to open the **export** function, and export it.
8. You get an image (png or jpg) which you can include using various packages into a LaTeX file.

This gives the middle image (the above process took ~10 seconds):
[image]
Because it's an svg file, you can use the node tool (select the line drawing, then press N) to tweak the image a bit, change its colour, etc., e.g. giving the above picture on the right.

Here is another example, based on a random maths drawing I found online. The last one took about a minute to (badly) edit.

[image]

Tip: do not delete the inkscape file, so that you can re-edit the image later if you like.

Answer (score 20):

[TikZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGF/TikZ) (a self-referential acronym for *Tikz Ist Kein Zeichenprogramm*) is an excellent, and extremely versatile drawing program. I highly recommend it.

There's an extensive [manual](https://pgf-tikz.github.io/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf). It might be frightening at first sight, but it in fact starts very gently, with a long list of worked examples (starting on page 30).

There's also some humorous examples of things not to do when designing a graphic (check out the stuff around page 99).

Comment: On top of the manual, https://tex.stackexchange.com/ has some amazing examples illiustrating the power of TikZ.

Comment: As you already wrote in German, TikZ ist *not* a drawing program. ;)

Comment: @Keba. Point taken. I understand that Tikz *claims* not to be  drawing program... But it is a program that people use to produce figures, a.k.a. drawings.  :-)

Answer (score 13):

In the case you prefer to draw pictures on a computer without entering the source code manually, I recommend [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/), which is a free, opens source vector graphics editor. It has a Latex plugin that allows you to include math formulae, as well as a variety of other tools.

It outputs an .svg file, which is essentially an .xml document describing your graphics, so in principle it can be edited by a human. Also, many programming languages have tools to create .svg files, e.g., the [swgwrite](https://pypi.org/project/svgwrite/) package in Python. Computer algebra systems allow one to save their graphics in .svg, that can then be edited in Inkscape.

For conversion between Tikz and .svg, see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51757/how-can-i-use-tikz-to-make-standalone-svg-graphics) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370876/converting-an-svg-image-to-tikz-code).

Comment: There is also https://www.diagrams.net/, which I personally prefer over Inkscape, although it may serve a slightly different purpose. It also offers the ability to write LaTeX inside figures.

Answer (score 3):

I find Inkscape a bit too heavy and use a much smaller vector drawing program for Windows called [Mayura Draw](http://www.mayura.com/) in combination with equally antiquated [psfrag](https://ctan.org/pkg/psfrag?lang=en) package.